# Literally draw a function and convert it to x and y points arrays

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I'm looking for free tool (eventually commercial) for drawing plot - I mean literally: with pencil. This plots are going to be for simple demonstration. **This tool should convert my drawings to x and y points arrays.** That's all.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I want to draw it from scratch on computer. By pencil I mean "free drawing tool" or something in this area.

Comment: As regards myself, when I need to draw simple things with a few freehand curves and annotations, I use the graphical editor in MS Word (!) It can produce good quality antialiased drawings, including splines. Unfortunately, I know of no ready-made tool that will output coordinate lists for you. (If you are ready to spend some time, I am sure a Word macro can do the trick.)